# Long Running Magento cron

Tags: cron

I've been noticing the Magento cron job running for over 10 hours now. An strace only shows polls. However I do see the following query running

```
SELECT
    `e`.*, `at_visibility`.`value` AS `visibility`
FROM
    `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (
    `at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`
)
AND (
    `at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '95'
)
AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 0)
WHERE
    (at_visibility. VALUE = '4')
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 329420
```

Any ideas what Magento is doing right now? How can I debug this further?

Comment: That is a reindex i think.

Comment: LIMIT 10 OFFSET 329420 man it takes lot of data to process, try to run this query with explain and it will explain what it does and how hard it hits the db

Comment: great and what did you found out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be part of the product catalog reindex.